# Writing to a memory address using python

Tags: python, dma

I am working with some memory address and need to read and write those locations. From the main system I am accessing a linux subsystem and trying to write to a memory location which is only accessible to that subsystem

The plan is to ssh from main system and do some task using a python script which will require python to write a struct into that memory starting from the base address

So far C++ is what I was using to actually directly allocate some memory from the starting base address *_location_I_wish_to_write* since now the memory is only accessible by the subsystem I am thinking of writing a python script which will actually do the same thing but cannot find a suitable reference to do so

If python wants to be simple, is there a way to actually map the *_location_I_wish_to_write* to the *some_struct* using C++ and simply assign the struct values like the code snippet given below?

```cpp
// need to set the struct here at _location_I_wish_to_write
some_struct * some_struct_name = (some_struct *)&_location_I_wish_to_write[0];
memset(some_struct_name , 0x00, sizeof(some_struct ));
some_struct_name->some_value = 0x1;
```

Comment: Memory management is complicated and python wants to be easy. So it's very unlikely there's a command. But why can't you use your C++ script?

Comment: That could be done, I was just wondering about a pythonic way of doing it

Comment: Example using [ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) shows [How do you write a full struct to shared memory in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202481/how-do-you-write-a-full-struct-to-shared-memory-in-python)